# Double value not getting displayed correctly in WPF 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

We have a textbox in an application which displays a double value. This textbox is connected to a converter which takes the string, converts it into a double and rounds it to 2 decimal places. Then the same converter converts back the double to a string and passes it back to the view.

Now about the problem we're facing. The issue is that rounding up is working as expected, but rounding down is not working. For eg., if we put 1.229 in the textbox, it will automatically round it up to 1.23, whereas if we put 1.224 it doesn't round it down to 1.22

I've looked more deep into the problem and found out that the actual rounding is working fine, whereas there seems to be problem in the process when the rounded value gets transferred to the view. 
To explain a little more about my finding, if I put a breakpoint on Math.Round the result thrown back by it, is the expected one. But when the same value gets returned back to the view, for some reason the value gets changed and what gets shown in the textbox is not the expected one.

I changed the framework of the project to 4.5 and found that this problem is non-existent in .NET Framework 4.5 and everything is working as expected. But we're using .NET Framework 4.0 and need a workaround.

Converter Code:

```
public class TextToNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        int decimalsValue = 2;
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out decimalsValue);
        }

        if (!double.IsNaN(System.Convert.ToDouble(value)))
        {
            result = string.Format("{0}", Math.Round((double)value, decimalsValue, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string inVal = (string)value;

        switch (targetType.Name)
        {
            case "Int32":
                return this.StringToInt32(inVal);
            case "Double":
                if (inVal != String.Empty &&
                inVal != "-" &&
                inVal != "-0" &&
                inVal != "-0," &&
                inVal != "-0." &&
                inVal != "-0,0" &&
                inVal != "-0.0")
                {
                    return this.StringToDouble(inVal);
                }
                else
                    return Double.NaN;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private int StringToInt32(string inVal)
    {
        int retVal = 0;

        // remove non-integer characters
        //string regExpressionPattern = "[^0-9-]";
        //inVal = Regex.Replace(inVal, regExpressionPattern, String.Empty);

        bool result = Int32.TryParse(inVal, out retVal);
        if (true == result)
        {
            return retVal;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private double StringToDouble(string inVal)
    {
        double retVal = double.NaN;

        // remove non-numeric characters
        //string regExpressionPattern = "[^0-9-.,]";
        //inVal = Regex.Replace(inVal, regExpressionPattern, String.Empty);
        inVal = Regex.Replace(inVal, "[,]", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

        bool result = Double.TryParse(inVal, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out retVal);
        if (true == result)
        {
            return retVal;
        }
        else
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class MainWindow_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private RxData _currentRxData_right;
    public RxData CurrentRxData_right
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentRxData_right == null)
                _currentRxData_right = new RxData();

            return _currentRxData_right;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentRxData_right = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentRxData_right"));
        }
    }
}
```

Model code:

```
public class RxData
{
   public double Sphere { get; set; }
}
```

Textbox for data input:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt_sph" Text="{Binding CurrentRxData_right.Sphere, Converter={StaticResource TextToNumber}, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:F2\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=NULL}" ></TextBox>
```

Comment: please dont share code like that. put part of your code that you know is causing problem. if you cannot format your code correctly in question just leave it. we do it for you. you can still [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33498822/edit) your question and write your code in it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I've put out the code sample link and included the code itself in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The good old trick of reduction by 0.005 would do the job:

- 1.224 - 0.005 = 1.219 ==Round=> 1.22.
- 1.229 - 0.005 = 1.224 ==Round=> 1.23.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Giora.
But this did not help us, as we've found that the actual rounding is working fine whereas the value gets changed when passed back to the view.